# How to use LinqToTwitter in UAP?

Tags: linq-to-twitter

I started to try using Linq to Twitter library to query some twitter data. I have a following function:

```
public static async Task<List<Status>> GetTweets(TwitterContext context, string searchQuery, int count = 15)
    {
        var searchResult = await
            (from search in context.Search
             where search.Type == SearchType.Search &&
                   search.Query == searchQuery &&
                   search.IncludeEntities == true &&
                   search.Count == count
             select search)
             .SingleOrDefaultAsync();

        return searchResult.Statuses;
    }
```

And the function in a console application I created to call this function looks like this:

```
IAuthorizer authorizer = new ApplicationOnlyAuthorizer
        {
            CredentialStore = new InMemoryCredentialStore
            {
                ConsumerKey = consumerKey,
                ConsumerSecret = consumerSecret,
            }

        };
        authorizer.AuthorizeAsync().Wait();
        TwitterContext context = new TwitterContext(authorizer);
        List<Status> statuses = GetTweets(context, "#hashtag", 50).Result;
```

This works perfectly. However, if I migrate this into a universal windows app, then it hangs at `List<Status> statuses = GetTweets(context, "#hashtag", 50).Result;` forever. No exception occurs, nothing shows up, nothing returns. Am I using it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Versions of LINQ to Twitter v3.x and earlier won't work with UAP apps. They'll produce the same behavior that you're experiencing now. You must upgrade to the latest version, which is in pre-release.

Here's the pre-release version of LINQ to Twitter, v4.0. It's main purpose is to include support for UAP, in addition to other technologies:

http://www.nuget.org/packages/linqtotwitter/4.0.0-beta2